# FW/1 URL Encoding Subsystems

Tags: plugins, frameworks, coldfusion, fw1, mura

I am creating an FW/1 based plugin for Mura CMS, and after I installed it I was getting permanent redirect errors in my browser.  I noticed that my URL which should be `/plugins/studentms/?action=admin:main.default` was being turned into `/plugins/studentms/?action=admin%3Amain.default`.  I don't know what I might have set that is causing that.  The template for the FW/1 plugin by Steve Withington works just fine, and when I was developing my app as a normal FW/1 application it worked fine.

If I try to go straight to either the root of the plugin (`/plugins/studentms`) or directly to the proper URL then it redirects to the URL encoded format.

Anyone have any ideas as to what would cause that?

PS I have tried in multiple browsers.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/framework-one/browse_thread/thread/b3210d115fd2ff01